# How to match usb device listed with lsusb with usb serial number displayed with dmesg?

Tags: linux, usb, wireshark, tshark, dmesg

I have a setup here with a lot of USB devices connected
this is my `lsusb` output:

```
Bus 003 Device 013: ID 16c0:05dc Van Ooijen Technische Informatica shared ID for use with libusb
Bus 003 Device 014: ID 16c0:05dc Van Ooijen Technische Informatica shared ID for use with libusb
Bus 003 Device 011: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 003 Device 015: ID 16c0:05dc Van Ooijen Technische Informatica shared ID for use with libusb
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 003 Device 016: ID 16c0:05dc Van Ooijen Technische Informatica shared ID for use with libusb
Bus 003 Device 017: ID 16c0:05dc Van Ooijen Technische Informatica shared ID for use with libusb
Bus 003 Device 018: ID 16c0:05dc Van Ooijen Technische Informatica shared ID for use with libusb
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 16c0:05dc Van Ooijen Technische Informatica shared ID for use with libusb
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 08bb:29c6 Texas Instruments PCM2906C Audio CODEC
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0424:2517 Standard Microsystems Corp. Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 16c0:05dc Van Ooijen Technische Informatica shared ID for use with libusb
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 16c0:05dc Van Ooijen Technische Informatica shared ID for use with libusb
Bus 001 Device 015: ID 16c0:05dc Van Ooijen Technische Informatica shared ID for use with libusb
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 04b4:00f8 Cypress Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 04b4:00f3 Cypress Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 016: ID 16c0:05dc Van Ooijen Technische Informatica shared ID for use with libusb
Bus 001 Device 017: ID 16c0:05dc Van Ooijen Technische Informatica shared ID for use with libusb
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

as you can see there are multiple of the same devices and multiple hubs with the same vendor id and all.
I am monitoring these with Wireshark (tshark actually) and I get some errors like this:

```
293549  43.514117       3.17.1 → host         USB 66 URB_BULK in[Malformed Packet]
```

However, I can't physically identify which device it is without the device's serial number.

I can see this serial number on dmesg

```
[Wed Feb 17 16:03:29 2021] usb 1-3.2.1: New USB device found, idVendor=16c0, idProduct=05dc
[Wed Feb 17 16:03:29 2021] usb 1-3.2.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[Wed Feb 17 16:03:29 2021] usb 1-3.2.1: Product: USB BDC
[Wed Feb 17 16:03:29 2021] usb 1-3.2.1: Manufacturer: www.engineeredarts.co.uk
[Wed Feb 17 16:03:29 2021] usb 1-3.2.1: SerialNumber: 345B34673238
```

My question is: How can I match these two things? or at least, how can I get that same 'SerialNumber' that `dmesg` displays, of the numbers I get from tshark?

(resetting each device to see which one is which while watching dmesg and lsusb isn't an option)

Answer (score 0):

Got it!
Turns out you can see the serial with `sudo lsusb -v`. It has to be run as root otherwise the files will be empty, then to clean all the useless info did a quick grep like so:

```
lsusb -v | grep '^Bus\|iSerial'
```

This is grepping 2 results (separated by \| which is the OR operator), first one are stuff that start(^) with the word Bus and the second one is that it contains the word serial

also stumbled across another command that I didn't know about:

```
usb-devices
```